# Using lists , place numbers in ascending order

Tags: c

How do i make this code place numbers in ascending order?

Im kinda new to lists and i really want to have this as an example,
and without any functions from headerfiles.(other than malloc i guess)

As a first im getting an error(.exe stopped working),dont know where its from.(possibly its when appendref is executed)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct box{
    int value;
    struct box*next;
};
typedef struct box Box;

Box *createbox(int a){
    Box *newbox_ptr;
    newbox_ptr=malloc(sizeof(Box));
    newbox_ptr->next=NULL;
    newbox_ptr->value=a;
    return newbox_ptr;
}
void report(Box *mylist_ptr){
    if(mylist_ptr==NULL){
        return;
    }
    printf("%d:",mylist_ptr->value);
    report(mylist_ptr->next);
    return;
}
void appendref(Box **start_ptrptr,Box *node_ptr){
    Box *iter=*start_ptrptr;
    if(iter==NULL){
        printf("Called with empty list\n");

        *start_ptrptr=node_ptr;
    }
    for(;iter->next!=NULL;iter=iter->next);
    iter->next=node_ptr;
    return;
}
int main(){
    Box *mylist=NULL;
    Box *new_ptr;
    new_ptr=createbox(7);
    report(new_ptr);
    printf("%p\n",(void *)mylist);
    appendref(&mylist,new_ptr);
    printf("%p\n",(void *)mylist);
    report(mylist);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ".exe stopped working" is not helpful. Show some scholarship and tell us more about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does segmentation fault in function `appendref` in line:

```
for(;iter->next!=NULL;iter=iter->next);
```

That's because local variable `iter` is equal to NULL, ie:

```
void appendref(Box **start_ptrptr,Box *node_ptr){
    Box *iter = *start_ptrptr; // *start_ptrptr = NULL
    if(iter==NULL){ // this is true
        printf("Called with empty list\n");

        *start_ptrptr = node_ptr;
        // iter = NULL, and we go on...
    }
    for(;iter->next!=NULL;iter=iter->next); // iter = NULL -> segfault
    iter->next=node_ptr;
    return;
}
```

I suggest adding a return in the if statement:

```
void appendref(Box **start_ptrptr,Box *node_ptr){
    Box *iter = *start_ptrptr;
    if(iter == NULL){
        printf("Called with empty list\n");
        *start_ptrptr = node_ptr;
        return;
    }
    for(;iter->next!=NULL;iter=iter->next);
    iter->next=node_ptr;
}
```

As for placing the numbers in ascending order the code needs much more work:

```
void appendref(Box **head,Box *node) {
    // if the list is empty, just append node_ptr to the list
    if(*head == NULL){
        *head = node;
        return;
    }
    // find Box with value lower then node->value, but the next Box has higher value then node->value
    if ((*head)->value > node->value) {
        // insert new head
        node->next = *head;
        *head = node;
    } else {
        Box *iter = *head;
        for(iter = *head; iter->next != NULL; iter = iter->next) {
            assert(iter->value <= iter->next->value); // assert the list is sorted in ascending order
            // break if the next node has higher value then added node
            if (iter->next->value > node->value)
                break;
        }
        // insert node after iter
        node->next = iter->next;
        iter->next = node;
    }
}
```

You might interest yourself in generic list helping macros from *bsd in [sys/queue.h](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/sys/queue.h) .

Comment: what is head and temp?Also THANO YOU SIR.

Comment: `Box **head` is the list head, ie. pointer to the first element in the list, you called that `start_ptrptr`, i find `head` more readable. I wanted `Box *temp` to serve as some saving variable for iter->next, but i see now it isn't needed (good catch), i have edited the answer.

Comment: if u can pop on my last question and help me  you help a ton ;)